# Grouping by week and summing left joined field in a postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to measure the participation rate in my events on a weekly basis per client. My tables:

- Table `event` has a `start_date`, `max_nb_of_bookings`, `group_id` fields
- Table `booking` has a `event_id` field that link to the event id.

I have currently the sum of bookings per week for a given group (:

```
select count(distinct booking.id) as bookings,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
from event
       left join booking on event.id = booking.event_id
where event.group_id = 2
group by week
order by week desc
```

Which gives me something like

```
bookings | week
-------------------------------------
8        | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000
39       | 2019-01-28 00:00:00.000000
39       | 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000000
35       | 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000000
39       | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000000
14       | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000
0        | 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000
```

So far, so good. I can have the cumulative number of available booking places as well:

```
select sum(event.max_nb_of_bookings) as places,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
from event
where event.group_id = 2
group by week, event.id
order by week desc
```

Which gives me:

```
places | week
-----------------------------------
54     | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000
54     | 2019-01-28 00:00:00.000000
63     | 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000000
48     | 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000000
49     | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000000
36     | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000
12     | 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000
```

Now I want the percentage ratio:

```
select round(1.0 * count(distinct booking.id) / sum(event.max_nb_of_bookings) * 100, 2) as filling,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
from event
left join booking on event.id = booking.event_id
where event.group_id = 2
group by week
order by week desc
```

And I get this:

```
filling | week
------------------------------------
12.12   | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000
16.25   | 2019-01-28 00:00:00.000000
16.05   | 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000000
16.67   | 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000000
17.41   | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000000
14.58   | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000
0       | 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000
```

This is weird because most of them should be above 50%. And when I ask for the two separate values, I see the problem:

```
select count(distinct booking.id) as bookings,
       sum(event.max_nb_of_bookings) as places,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
from event
       left join booking on event.id = booking.event_id
where event.group_id = 2
group by week
order by week desc
```

```
bookings | places | week
----------------------------------------------
8        | 66     | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000
39       | 240    | 2019-01-28 00:00:00.000000
39       | 243    | 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000000
35       | 210    | 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000000
39       | 224    | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000000
14       | 96     | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000
0        | 12     | 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000
```

It seems like the "distinct" from one select statement is messing up the "sum" from the other statement. If I try grouping by event I loose the per-week sums... I could use some help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the different grouping's you have for count(distinct booking.id) for sum(event.max_nb_of_bookings)

Eg:

In the below query, you are counting the distinct booking.id per week

```
select count(distinct booking.id) as bookings,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
  from event
left join booking on event.id = booking.event_id
where event.group_id = 2
group by week /*Note the group by is by week only*/
```

And here you are summing up the event.max_nb_of_bookings by week per event.id

```
select sum(event.max_nb_of_bookings) as places,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
from event
where event.group_id = 2
group by week, event.id /*Group by event.id and week*/
```

So in your record set you could have a result set as follows

```
places | week                       |event.id  
-----------------------------------
54     | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000 |1
12     | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000 |2 ---> There can be a record as follows 
54     | 2019-01-28 00:00:00.000000 |3
63     | 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000000 |3
48     | 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000000 |4
49     | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000000 |5
36     | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000 |6
12     | 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000 |7
```

Therefore the output of

select sum(event.max_nb_of_bookings) as places,
       date_trunc('week', event.start_date::date) as week
from event
where event.group_id = 2
group by week

would be

```
places | week                       
-----------------------------------
66     | 2019-02-04 00:00:00.000000 
54     | 2019-01-28 00:00:00.000000 
63     | 2019-01-21 00:00:00.000000 
48     | 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000000 
49     | 2019-01-07 00:00:00.000000 
36     | 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000 
12     | 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: I know what is causing the issue, but I can't see an answer in your post. I'm not enough at ease with sql comands to make both calculations correct in the same query. Maybe it's impossible and that would be a good enough answer too